# How to create txt file

Tags: vb6

I have to create a txt file so with some large content in VB6. Can anybody help me out on this and please tell me the references also.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**This is how you can create a text file in VB6**

```
Dim iFileNo as Integer
iFileNo = FreeFile
'open the file for writing
Open "C:\Test.txt" For Output As #iFileNo
'please note, if this file already exists it will be overwritten!

'write some example text to the file
Print #iFileNo, "first line of text"
Print #iFileNo, " second line of text"
Print #iFileNo, "" 'blank line
Print #iFileNo, "some more text!"

'close the file (if you dont do this, you wont be able to open it again!)
Close #iFileNo
```

[Source](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?342619.html)

Answer (score 19):

how large?

to keep it simple:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 textbox: name=Text1
'  1 command button: name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim intFile As Integer
  Dim strFile As String
  strFile = "c:\temp\file.txt" 'the file you want to save to
  intFile = FreeFile
  Open strFile For Output As #intFile
    Print #intFile, Text1.Text 'the data you want to save
  Close #intFile
End Sub
```

this will replace the file each time you click the command button, if you want to add to the file then you can open "for append" instead of "for output"

[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266177%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)