# How to Save listview items to a text file on VB6

Tags: listview, text, vb6

I have data in my listview1 like this:

[image: listview]

And i want to save Quantity until Total cost Coloum from that listview to .txt
but i dont know how to save it to .txt

i found the referencee drom another web, they used this code:

```
Private Sub testfile as String = application.startupPath & "\testfile.txt"
```

### print(click)

```
Dim mywriter as new.IO.streamwriter(testfile)
    for eacy myItem as ListviewItem in Listview1.items
        mywriter.writeLine(myitem.text & "#" & myItem.SubItem(1).text & "#" & myitem.subitem(2).text)
    next
    mywriter.close()
```

but VB6 can't compile this code.
please help me

Comment: the snippet is VB.NET, not classic VB, just look here: [VB6 - How to create txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108664/how-to-create-txt-file)

Comment: oh! thankyou so much :))

Comment: `Private Sub testfile as String` is not valid syntax. `Sub` is for making a subroutine.

Comment: @deblocker what code on VB6 for this coding? private sub button2_click(byval sender as system.object byval e as system.eventargs ) on VB.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListItems` and `ListSubItems` are *Base 1*, this means they are starting from index 1 and you will find it in the same order as you have added it to the `ListView`.

For example: the Price for product "a" is in `ListView1.ListItems(2).SubItems(4)` because the first column is the `ListItem` Itself, which you can get as follows : `ListView1.ListItems(2).Text`.

So, if your question is about printing to file, you may need some small, optional, helper functions, which you can always keep in your snippet library, for example in a `module`, and (maybe) reuse.

Please, keep in mind there are really a lot of ways to get your task done, this is just an example.

```
Public Function NormalizePath(path As String) As String
    ' Normalize a Windows path with Backslash
    Const DirSeparator = "\"
    If Right(path, 1) = DirSeparator Then
        NormalizePath = path
    Else
        NormalizePath = path & DirSeparator
    End If
End Function

Public Function Formatted(TextValue, FormatType, ColumnWidth) As String
    ' Make fixed length fields
    Dim Result As String, PlaceHolder As String
    Dim CurrencyValue As Currency
    PlaceHolder = Space(ColumnWidth)
    Select Case FormatType
        Case "Text"
            Result = Left(TextValue & PlaceHolder, ColumnWidth)
        Case "Integer"
            Result = Right(PlaceHolder & TextValue, ColumnWidth)
        Case "Currency"
            CurrencyValue = CCur(TextValue)
            Result = Right(PlaceHolder & Format(CurrencyValue, "0.00"), ColumnWidth)
    End Select
    Formatted = Result
End Function
```

Now to the point: double-click your `CommandButton` labeled *Print Receipt* and write this code:

```
PrintReceipt
```

Copy and paste following function to your form:

```
Private Sub PrintReceipt()
On Error GoTo PrintReceipt_Error
    Dim LineText As String, CellText As String
    Dim TotalAmt As Currency, FormattedTotalAmt As String
    Dim FileNum As Integer, FullFileName As String, i As Long, l As Long

    FullFileName = NormalizePath(App.path) & "Receipt.txt"
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open FullFileName For Output As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, "| " & Formatted("Qty.", "Text", 5) & " | " & Formatted("Product Name", "Text", 12) & " | " & Formatted("Unit Amt.", "Text", 9) & " | " & Formatted("Amount", "Text", 12) & " | "
    Print #FileNum, String(2 * 2 + 3 * 3 + 5 + 12 + 9 + 12, "-")
    l = ListView1.ListItems.Count
    For i = 1 To l
        LineText = "| "
        CellText = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(2) 'Quantity
        LineText = LineText & Formatted(CellText, "Integer", 5) & " | "
        CellText = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(3) 'Product_Name
        LineText = LineText & Formatted(CellText, "Text", 12) & " | "
        CellText = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(4) 'Price
        LineText = LineText & Formatted(CellText, "Currency", 9) & " | "
        CellText = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(5)  'Total_Cost
        LineText = LineText & Formatted(CellText, "Currency", 12) & " | "
        TotalAmt = TotalAmt + CCur(CellText)
        Print #FileNum, LineText
    Next
    FormattedTotalAmt = Format(TotalAmt, "0.00")
    Print #FileNum, String(2 * 2 + 3 * 3 + 5 + 12 + 9 + 12, "-")
    Print #FileNum, Formatted("", "Text", 2 + 3 + 5) & Formatted("Total Amount", "Text", 12) & String(27 - Len(FormattedTotalAmt), ".") & FormattedTotalAmt
    Close #FileNum 'Close the file
    Exit Sub
PrintReceipt_Error:
    Close #FileNum 'Always close the file
End Sub
```

If you did it all right, you will find inside the path of your project a nicely formatted copy of your received data. Open the text file with Notepad and from menu *Format*->*Font* choose a fixed-width font, for example *Courier New*. You should be able to see something like this:

[image]

The coolest thing you can do now with this file, is to send it back to your device as *Order Confirmation*.

**Final notes:**

- familiarize and try to understand the terms: *Quantity*, *Base
  Quantity*, *Unit Price* and *Unit Cost*. They have all different
  meanings. Will be the *Quantity* always an *Integer*?
- you haven't assigned to your received data any identifier, so i
  believe your biggest problem now will be how to keep track of all the
  received messages because the file will be always overwritten without
  warning. Up to you, if you need it, to analyze the problem and find
  out how to set your filename to a meaningful unique identifier, for
  example: *Receipt_0001.txt* or something like this.

Happy learning!

Comment: thankyouu so much. you always help me to learning :) yees i will try this . thankyouuuu