# How to read and write comma delimited text values to file in VB 6.0

Tags: csv, vb6

Okay let's say I have sample text file that includes some comma delimited values like so:

```
-1,0,3,0,5,4,6,7,8,9
```

And I want to make a program in VB 6.0 that opens that file, read the values and store them in variables which are displayed in text boxes like so (example):

```
Name: [ Value -1 ]
Nationality: [ Value 0 ]
Experience: [ Value 3 ]
```

and so on ..

So when I chance these values in the program text boxes and hit save file - it saves the file with the new values. Is that simple. Thank you guys !

Comment: Could you post your code through edit this question?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a code. That why I am asking how it's done. I am still searching for it, but its very hard to find something about VB 6.0

Comment: Shouldn't be hard, since every legal copy of VB6 comes with online documentation in the MSDN CDs included in the package.  No MSDN CDs means not a legal copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: this answer is assuming that the text file only contains one line.)

First, you will need to read the text file:

```
Dim rawData as string

Dim sFileText as String
Dim FileNo as Integer
FileNo = FreeFile
Open "C:\test.txt" For Input As #FileNo 'you should change the file path
Line Input #FileNo, sFileText 'read the whole line
rawData = sFileText 'store the first line of the text file in 'rawData'
Close #FileNo
```

Next, you need to split the rawData by the commas:

```
Dim data() as string 'an array that will hold each value
data = Split(rawData, ",") 'split 'rawData' with a comma as delimiter
```

Now the first value is stored in data(0), second in data(1), etc.

As far as the 'save file' button, you can do something like:

```
Dim newData as String
newData = data(0) & "," & data(1) & "," & data(2) 'etc.
```

Then [write it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108664/how-to-create-txt-file).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The file will be automatically comma-delimited if you do this:

```
Write #filenumer Value1, Value2, Value3...
```

Then you can use Input # to get one value at a time or Line Input to get them all at once.